# Ordem sujeito-verbo nas orações

Tags: ordem-de-expressões, sintaxe

O latim permitia uma ordem muito flexível na construção das orações.  Algumas das línguas latinas como o francês perdeu essa flexibilidade e outras como o espanhol em maior parte a conservou, permitindo todo tipo de ordens.

A ordem normal no português é sujeito-verbo, mas tenho notado que o português às vezes (mas não tanto quanto as suas línguas irmãs que falo) permite uma ordem invertida de verbo-sujeito, mas não percebo quando devo ou posso inverter a ordem e quando mantê-la.

Já que sempre é mais fácil com um exemplo, numa composição que eu escrevi para uma aula, tive «Esse dia mesmo, depois dela se afastar, *saiu o rapaz* para o campo…».  O professor corregiu-me essa parte em itálico para «o rapaz saiu».

Não obstante, só olhando a primeira página do livro *O mulato*, achei vários exemplos desta inversão e não entendo porque o meu uso é incorreto, mas o de Aluísio Azevedo é considerado correto:

> - De um casebre miserável, de porta e janela, **oiviam-se gemer os armadores** enferrujados…
> - De uma gaiola, dependurada entre as janelas desse lado, **chilreava um sabiá.**
> - **Fazia** preguiça **estar ali**.
> - E, quando **chegava a ocasião** de ceder a fazenda…

Pergunto quais situações é normal/possível/proibida a inversão de sujeito e verbo?  Por que a minha frase é errada e as de Azevedo não são?

Comment: Não sei os motivos de seu professor, mas não há nada de errado nessa inversão. O uso de "saiu o rapaz" é muito comum no meio literário (mas não é exclusivo).

Comment: @guifa: Estou curioso em saber se a minha previsão está correta. O gemido dos armadores e chilrear do sabiá são apenas parte do ambiente e não da ação principal?

Comment: pretérito imperfeito usado na construção de frase de Aluisio Azevedo enquanto você utilizou o normal. O correto seria: Esse dia mesmo, depois dela se afastar, **saía** o rapaz para o campo. Corrija-me se estiver errado.

Comment: O francês faz inversão de outro tipo.

Answer (score 4):

A tua frase não está errada, mas é provável que a ordem ‘normal’ *sujeito-verbo* seja aí mais natural. Só poderia dar uma opinião mais inequívoca se visse a frase completa.

Vou limitar-me a analisar os exemplos do Aluísio Azevedo, tentar encontrar padrões, para no fim discutir a tua frase. Este assunto daria pano para mangas, e eu não conseguiria compor aqui um guia minimamente completo da ordem *verbo-sujeito*. E noutro lado, provavelmente também não.

No primeiro exemplo do autor,

> De um casebre miserável, de porta e janela, (1) **ouviam-se gemer os armadores** enferrujados…

temos dois verbos antes de *armadores*. Para os estudar separadamente, consideremos primeiro esta frase equivalente (mas menos bem-sonante):

> De um casebre miserável, de porta e janela, (1a) **ouviam-se os armadores** enferrujados **gemer**

A frase (1a) está na [voz passiva sintética](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/vozes-do-verbo/), e aí a norma é a ordem *verbo-sujeito paciente*, **ouviam-se os armadores**. Até porque *os armadores ouviam-se gemer* confunde-se com a voz ativa: os armadores ouviam-se a si mesmos. Na voz ativa a frase seria *alguém ouvia os armadores enferrujados gemer* (*sujeito agente-verbo*) e na passiva analítica seria *os armadores enferrujados eram ouvidos gemendo/a gemer* (neste caso a sintética soa muito melhor que a analítica). Na voz passiva analítica é mais comum a ordem *sujeito paciente-verbo*, embora a inversa seja possível (*todas as vítimas foram socorridas/foram socorridas todas as vítimas*)

Agora, a diferença entre (1a) ouviam-se **os armadores gemer** e (1) ouviam-se **gemer os armadores**. O primeiro elemento ganha ênfase. Em (1a) estamos mais interessados nos armadores, por que razão estarão eles a gemer; em (1) estamos mais interessados no *gemer* em si, e na maneira como o *gemer* contribui para a atmosfera geral. Isso passa-se também na voz ativa, como no segundo exemplo, **chilreava um sabiá**. Não conheço *O Mulato*, mas diria que o autor está a descrever o ambiente: o foco está mais no *chilrear* e *gemer* que se ouve do que no agente que chilreia ou que geme. Do mesmo modo, eu poderia dizer ao descrever um ambiente:

> (a) Da minha janela eu via passar os carros, brincar os miúdos, cair a chuva, cumprimentarem-se os amigos.
> (b) Na praça era uma alegria: corria a garotada, namoriscavam os adolescentes, conversavam os mais velhos.

Esta inversão da ordem mais normal é frequentemente usada para ‘montar a cena’ para a ação principal:

> (c) Estava eu mergulhado nos meus pensamentos, quando de repente ele me apareceu à frente.
> (d) **Ia o João** muito bem a caminho da escola, e **cai-lhe um pombo morto** em cima da cabeça.

Em (d) há uma segunda inversão. O verbo *cair* ganha ênfase ao ser adiantado: nós não queremos saber do pombo morto; a queda dele na cabeça do João é que é importante. Outros exemplos de inversão em que identidade do sujeito não é importante:

> (e) Foi cá um temporal: **tombaram duas árvores** na minha rua e **voaram muitas telhas** com a ventania.
> (f) **Deram** à costa vários **destroços** do navio naufragado. **Sobreviveram** apenas **cinco pessoas**.

No terceiro exemplo, **faz preguiça estar aqui**, o núcleo do sujeito é um verbo, **estar**. A inversão soa muito bem com este tipo de sujeitos:

> (g) Fazia dó ver tanta miséria. Custou-me muito aguentar aquilo.
> (h) Não é assim tão caro fazer uma alimentação saudável.

No último exemplo, **e, quando chegava a ocasião de ceder a fazenda,** mais uma vez está-se a ‘montar a cena’ para a ação principal. Mas há ainda outra coisa: verbos qeu indicam aparecimento e desaparecimento parecem prestar-se particularmente à inversão, mesmo quando descrevem a ação principal, como de (l) a (n):

> (i) Quando chegavam os meus primos, então é que era uma festa.
> (j) Quando começaram a cair os primeiros flocos de neve, a garotada veio toda para a rua.
> (k) Quando apareceram os primeiros computadores pessoais, ninguém imaginou a revolução que iria acontecer.
> (l) Desapareceu de casa dos seus pais Fulano de 17 anos de idade etc. (Forma padrão de publicitar o desaparecimento de uma pessoa em Portugal.)
> (m)Apareceu-me uma mancha no pescoço.
> (n) Chegaram os teus primos agora mesmo.

Só depois de elaborar esta teoriazita da inversão da ordem normal *sujeito-verbo* é que consegui completar a tua frase, com **saiu o rapaz**, satisfatoriamente. Portanto, como o verbo ganha ênfase em detrimento do sujeito ao ser puxado para a frente, temos que encontrar um contexto em que isso se justifique. Portanto aqui ficam duas frases, uma em que **o rapaz saiu** se impõe, outra em que **saiu o rapaz** soa bem.

> (o) Nesse mesmo dia, depois de ela se afastar, o rapaz saiu para campo e só regressou a casa um semana mais tarde.
>
> (p) Nesse mesmo dia, depois de ela se afastar, saiu o rapaz para campo, e foi logo de seguida que os ladrões entraram em casa.

Answer (score 3):

> Esse dia mesmo, depois dela se afastar, saiu o rapaz para o campo…

O único erro de facto nesta frase é contrair "de" com "ela" em "dela". A contração não se faz quando há um sujeito em jogo: "Eu cheguei depois dela", mas "Eu cheguei depois de ela já lá ter estado três horas". Também é bem melhor dizer "esse mesmo dia" em lugar de "esse dia mesmo":

> Esse mesmo dia, depois de ela se afastar, saiu o rapaz para o campo…

Mas voltando ao tópico. Tenderia a concordar aqui com o teu professor. Talvez excluindo contextos em que a inversão é normal (e.g. perguntas, especialmente na escrita na variedade europeia, ou condicionais sem "se"), adiantar o verbo dá-lhe mais ênfase na frase. A tua frase não soa muito bem, creio eu, porque o foco dado a "sair" é despropositado -- a frase está simplesmente a descrever uma sequência de eventos, o que favorece a ordem normal.

A seguinte já é perfeitamente normal:

> Esse mesmo dia, lá sairia o rapaz para o campo.

Mas mesmo omitindo o "lá" (que ainda coloca mais o foco da frase em "sair", por oposição ao mero facto "o rapaz sair"; outros advérbios também serviriam como "imediamente"), a frase ainda soaria bem porque remover "depois de ela se afastar" tira-lhe algo do carácter meramente narrativo. Comparando:

> Esse mesmo dia, o rapaz sairia para o campo.
>   Esse mesmo dia, sairia o rapaz para o campo.

O significado é muito semelhante, mas a primeira, a ordem normal, apresenta o facto sem mais, enquanto a segunda é mais expressiva.

Creio que também se pode dar um argumento estrutural. É talvez mais fácil fazer uma inversão se já tiver havido outra antes (o que não é o caso na tua frase):

> Não fora ela afastar-se e fugiria o rapaz para o campo.
>   Se ela não se afastasse, fugiria o rapaz para o campo.

A primeira soa melhor.